# Installing custom ROM on HTC phones over Fastboot or ADB

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, fastboot

I am trying to build CyanogenMod for Sensation. After building I have `update.zip`, which I can install over CWM recovery manually. But how do I install the ROM over Fastboot or ADB in order to automate the installation process?

The same commands which I'm using for Google phones (Fastboot flash system) does not work normally. I think, that after flashing, system partition have wrong address.

Comment: You need to follow the usual installation steps (Use CWM for flashing .zip files and 'fastboot flash <partition> <partition>.img' for flashing image files (like boot.img). A .zip file is not a valid file system, it get's written as-is onto the partition you specify, fastboot just does what you ask for.

Comment: yes, i understand all about zip file. Problems in system.img, which we have after building in out folder - it have wrong file system for htc (yaff2 or ext3?) or offset, or something yet.